# Seeking opinions about a formula for OEIS

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, soft-question, pythagorean-triples

I proposed a formula

$a(n,k) = |A-B|=|j^2-2*k^2|, j=(2*n-1),\quad n,k \in N, GCD(j,k)=1,$

for the OEIS series
[Numbers whose prime factors are all congruent to +1 or -1 modulo 8.](https://oeis.org/draft/A058529)
$( 1, 7, 17, 23, 31, 41, 47, 49, 71, \cdots )$ that is in limbo because of a disagreement about the series being a function of $1$ variable or $2.\quad$ There is a problem with my formula in that no single variable will generate the entire series if the other variable is fixed.

I guess my questions are:

1. Should my formula be dropped?
2. Is there as single variable formula for the series?
3. Is there an argument in favor of keeping my formula?

I'm open to any ideas.

$\textbf{Update:}$ About the comments and one answer: The formula does not generate all natural numbers of the form $x^2-2y^2.\,$ It generates a subset of natural numbers of the form $(2x-1)^2-2y^2.$

I gather that the formula should probably be dropped because it there is no order in it, any more than there is for complex numbers. The lack or order makes it irrelevant that there are infinite combinations of $\,x,y\,$ that generate each number in the sequence.

Comment: Not really following their edit dialog, but it appears that there are two significant problems.  First of all, you certainly have not given a formula for the $n^{th}$ term, as you are aware.  Secondly, the formula for $a(n,k)$ and the geometric interpretation of it seem to have been discussed there already.  There's some issue with the signs...it's not instantly obvious to me that every natural number that can be written as $2n^2-k^2$ (with restrictions) can also be written as $x^2-2y^2$, though I haven't thought about it.  If that claim is true and non-obvious, maybe it is worth pointing out.

Comment: @lulu I acknowledge I cannot generate a(n) with one variable. Can you suggest a formula that can? I'm sure the OEIS community would love it.

Comment: Oh, I very much doubt that there is one.  But the non-existence of such a formula doesn't remedy the flaws with your proposal.  Like I said, I think it might be worth addressing the absolute value in your expression.  That adds something to the rest of the discussion.  Again, I haven't thought about the details so maybe it's obvious that this gives the same list, but if it isn't obvious, I'd say it was worth adding that.

Comment: @lulu You said absolute value might add something to the discussion but did not hint what that might be, The absolute value is necessary because, for instance

$F(1,2)\longrightarrow (5,12,13)\implies B-A=7\quad F(2,1)\longrightarrow (15,8,17)\implies B-A=-7$

Comment: I said exactly what I meant.  The duplicate comment in the OEIS text refers only to natural numbers expressible by the form $x^2-2y^2$.  Your expression also allows those expressible by the form $2y^2-x^2$.  It's not obvious to me that this is the same set of natural numbers.   Again, it might truly be obvious, but if it isn't I would draw attention to the fact (assuming it is a fact).

Comment: @lulu Your $\,x^2\,$ here is the set 
$\,\{1,9,25,\cdots\}\,$ and the result is the set
$\,\{1,7,17,23,\cdot\},\,$ not the set of natural numbers you suggest. Reversed or not, the formula generates the same set of numbers (signs reversed) and the absolute value is necessary to confine them to positive values only.

Comment: Once again:  The duplicate comment says the list consists of all natural numbers representable by the form $x^2-2y^2$ with $x$ odd and $\gcd(x,y)=1$.  You claim that it consists of all natural numbers representable by $|x^2-2y^2|$ with the same restrictions.  It is not obvious that those two lists coincide, though maybe they do.

Comment: For instance:  $41$ is representable your way if we take $(x,y)=(3,5)$.  But that particular pair doesn't work for the non-absolute version.  Of course, $41$ is also representable by the pair $(7,2)$ and that one does work for the first method.  This is probably a standard property of Pell's equation that I have forgotten, but, once again, the claim is not obvious to me (if it is obvious to someone else, I'd appreciate a quick proof or a reference).

Answer (score 0):

It is true that, as  Franklin T. Adams-Watters remarks in the first Comment to this sequence,  these are the natural numbers of the form $x^2 - 2 y^2$, where $x$ is odd and $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime.  That is not the same as saying that the sequence is a function of two variables $x$ and $y$.  In fact, the representation as $x^2 - 2 y^2$ is not unique, e.g.
$$ 7 = 3^2 - 2 \cdot 1^2 = 5^2 - 2 \cdot 3^2$$

Comment: You are correct in observing that the difference is not unique. All values are represented but, for instance,
$F(1,2)=F(2,1)=F(3,3)=F(3,4)=F(6,8)=F(7,9)=F(14,19)=F(16,22),\cdots=7.\quad$ Perhaps it is best to drop the formula from the series.

Comment: @poetasis In fact, for every value in the sequence, there are infinitely many possible ways of generating it as $x^2 - 2y^2$.

Comment: Yes, because $x^2 - 2 y^2 = n$ is a [Pell-type equation](https://imomath.com/index.cgi?page=ntPellsEquationPellType).